# How to perform quick printing without choosing lots of preferences with Google Apps Script in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, printing

everytime I want to print a Sheet in Google Sheets, I have to make lots of preferences before the Sheet is actually printed.

I want to find a workaround with Google Apps Script to set fixed printing preferences and I just need to press a button/menu then the printer will print that Sheet right away. Hope you guys could help me. Thanks in advance!

[image]

[image]

[image]

I tried to find code in Google but could not find the solution with my request.

Answer (score 1):

#### Workaround 1:

I am afraid you can not manage print settings using Google Apps Script, however you can achieve something similar by messing up with the file URL parameters and the export functionality, then combine that with the "Brother Email Print" feature and you could have an automated button that sends the file to your printer automatically.

Here is the script you can use:

```js
function emailToPrinter() {

  const baseURL = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getUrl().replace("/edit","");
  var url = baseURL+"/export"+
                              "?format=pdf&"+
                              "size=0&"+
                              "fzr=true&"+
                              "portrait=false&"+
                              "fitw=true&"+
                              "gridlines=false&"+
                              "printtitle=true&"+
                              "sheetnames=true&"+
                              "pagenum=CENTER&"+
                              "attachment=true";
                                                        
  var params = {method:"GET",headers:{"authorization":"Bearer "+ ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};
  
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getBlob();
  var printerEmail= "example123@print.brother.com";
  var subject= "Test email";
  var body= "";

  MailApp.sendEmail(printerEmail, subject, body, {
        attachments: [{
            fileName: "TEST ATTACHMENT" + ".pdf",
            content: response.getBytes(),
            mimeType: "application/pdf"
        }]
  });

}
```

For the script you can find additional URL parameters [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/130654/all-google-docs-url-parameters-functions-commands) and [here](https://groups.google.com/g/google-apps-script-community/c/mNAXmJcXDz4).

What the script does is to basically generate an export of the file using the parameters you need and send that as an attachment to the email address configured in your printer using the `Email Print` or the `Attach, Email, and Print` features of your Brother device, that way you do not need to click the print button anymore but it would be sent to your printer directly so you just have to go to your printer and select the file you want to print.

You may check the limitations of the features in the links below. Please also note that all these emails would be sent as you and therefore would appear in your `Sent` folder from Gmail.

#### Workaround 2:

If you have a Google Workspace account you can manage user policies for Chrome. Some of those policies are related to the default printer settings such as `Default printing page size`, `Restrict color printing mode`, `Print preview default` (you can set a default printer automatically for example), etc. The full list of policies can be found [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/2657289?hl=en#printing_enabled&disable_print_preview&enable_deprecated_privet_printing&disable_print_preview&cloud_print_submit_enabled&cloud_print_proxy_enabled&default_printer_pattern&native&user_native_printers_allowed&printing_color_default&printing_allowed_color_modes&printing_duplex_default&printing_allowed_duplex_modes&printing_background_graphics_default&printing_allowed_background_graphics_modes&printing_send_username_and_filename_enabled&print_job_history_expiration_period&delete_print_job_history_allowed&printing_allowed_pin_modes&printing_pin_default&printing_paper_size_enum&printing_max_sheets_allowed&print_header_footer&printer_type_deny_list&print_rasterization_mode&print_post_script_mode&print_pdf_as_image).

Please note that this option works only for Chrome.

However, I do think it would be great if Google could implement this as a feature. You could submit an issue tracker reporting this [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues).

#### References:

- [How to Email Print](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XMZGPgZAbPc)
- [How to setup and use Brother Email Print](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0_z7EbPO-jo)
- [How to use the Brother Attach, Email & Print function](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S6Kp_OdbO8s)

Comment: What a great workaround, Thanks @Fernando Lara so much.

Though, I still wait for someone has other solutions since going to the printer, finding the file and press the print button still need a lot of steps before getting to the printing step. :)

Comment: @LeCanh Are you using a Google Workspace account or a Gmail.com?

Comment: Hi @Fernando, I am using a gmail.com account. 
What could we achieve if I have a Google workspace account?

Comment: @LeCanh I edited my answer adding a bit more info about that.

Comment: What an another great workaround. Thanks @Fernado.